# Does mobile Google Chrome support browser extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can I create a plugin or an extension for Google Chrome MOBILE (Android Google Chrome)?

If not, can I create an extension for Google Chrome (desktop), which will add a button in Google Chrome bar. This button will open the page in another web browser (in my own web browser), so, this button should launch my own web browser.

Comment: mobile firefox supports extensions

Comment: Brave browser for Android (Chromium based) will add support for a subset of extension API and hand picked extensions (content scripts and background pages) in q2 of 2020: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/wiki/Roadmap#q2-2020-april---june

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Extensions are not supported, see: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/faq .

Specifically:

> **Does Chrome for Android now support the embedded WebView for a hybrid native/web app?**
>
> A Chrome-based WebView is included in Android 4.4 (KitKat) and later. See the [WebView overview](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) for details.
>
> **Does Chrome for Android support apps and extensions?**
>
> Chrome apps and extensions are currently not supported on Chrome for
>   Android. We have no plans to announce at this time.
>
> **Can I write and deploy web apps on Chrome for Android?**
>
> Though Chrome apps are not currently supported, we would love to see great interactive web sites accessible by URL.

Comment: thanks a lot for your precise response ! however, i'm just wondering if you know if there is a mobile web browser which support extensions or add-ons?

Comment: Firefox for Android supports add-ons. You use the [standard Firefox add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/). There are, however, [some limitations](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/mobile.html).

Comment: @Alaoui Dolphin browser has extensive add-in support for it's browser in addition to opera,  javelin,  CM Browser and a few otherS -- this applies to Android, that is.   I'm not sure about the availability of either the browsers or their add-on support (or lack thereof) on iOS.

Comment: Updated link to developing extensions for Firefox for Android: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Developing_WebExtensions_for_Firefox_for_Android

Comment: Google afraid of adlock XDDD

Answer (score 14):

You can use bookmarklets (javascript code in a bookmark) - this also means they sync across devices.

I have loads - I prefix the name with zzz, so they are eazy to type in to the address bar and show in drop down predictions.

To get them to operate on a page you need to go to the page and then in the address bar type the bookmarklet name - this will cause the bookmarklet to execute in the context of the page.

**edit**

Just to highlight - for this to work, the bookmarklet name must be typed into the address bar while the page you want to operate in is being displayed - if you go off to select the bookmarklet in some other way the page context gets lost, and the bookmarklet operates on a new empty page.

I use
zzzpocket - send to pocket.
zzztwitter tweet this page
zzzmail email this page
zzzpressthis send this page to wordpress
zzztrello send this page to trello
and more...

and it works in chrome whatever platform I am currently logged on to.

Answer (score 1):

Some extensions like blocksite use the accessibility service API to deploy extension like features to Chrome on Android. Might be worth a look through the play store. Otherwise, Firefox is your best bet, though many extensions don't work on mobile for some reason.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.blocksite&hl=en_US

Answer (score 1):

Just use a different browser.
Follow the steps given below to install Chrome extensions on your Android device.

Step 1: Open Google Play Store and download Yandex Browser. Install the browser on your phone.

Step 2: In the URL box of your new browser, open 'chrome.google.com/webstore’ by entering the same in the URL address.

Step 3: Look for the Chrome extension that you want and once you have it, tap on 'Add to Chrome.’

The added Chrome extension will now be automatically added to the Yandex browser.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that there are not many browsers supporting extension. Indeed, I have been interested in this question for the last year and I only found [Dolphin](http://dolphin-browser.com/) supporting add-ons and [other cool features](http://dev.dolphin-browser.com/get-started/) announced few days ago. I want to test it soon.

Comment: Xx xx, mobile Firefox also support extentions