# Chrome Extension for Android and Desktop?

Tags: android, google-chrome

This is probably a no, but if I develop a Chrome Extension for the normal desktop browser, and the extension relies on the Chrome API and normal Web API's, will it also work on Chrome for Android?  I couldn't find much on which API's are supported and which ones aren't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run chrome extension in android mobile chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765358/how-to-run-chrome-extension-in-android-mobile-chrome-browser) (I know that one was later but it apparently has more google guice so directing traffic there FWIW...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quote from the Google Chrome FAQ

> Does Chrome for Android support apps and extensions?
>      
> Chrome apps and extensions are currently not supported on Chrome for Android. We have no plans to announce at this time.

So in short the answer is no, Chrome for Android does not support extensions.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604417/browser-extension-support-in-google-chrome-on-mobile) an older Stack Overflow that asked a similar question