# How to run chrome extension in android mobile chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created chrome extension it's running in the web browser in desktop.But i am not able to download in mobile chrome browser.I want to run same extension in mobile and desktop chrome browser. So is there any way to run extension in mobile chrome browser.

Comment: Thus far I haven't found a good browser to do this.  There is a mobile browser called Snappy for android, but it's very hackish and require work to get it to suit your needs.  If you don't mind leaving a computer running I think I know of a possible loop hole... you could leave a remote desktop program like teamviewer running and use the mobile application to control your desktop and perform any actions needed.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185882/is-there-a-browser-on-android-accepting-extensions

Answer (score 12):

According to [chrome FAQ](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/faq), chrome for android will not support extensions or apps.

> Does Chrome for Android support apps and extensions?
>
> Chrome apps and extensions are currently not supported on Chrome for Android. We have no plans to announce at this time.

Comment: man, this stupid issue has been blocking me from even starting developing an extension for Chrome for like 5 years now, which I have a feeling means I am never going to have the functionality I need!

Comment: @Michael: how about firefox mobile?

Comment: You could just make developers develop plugins simultaneously for Mobiles by giving some tools. It would be a profit for you. Otherwise other Browsers can take advantage of

Answer (score 5):

You can use yandex browser on android and going to chrome Web store and add extension 
This link below it's show you how to use it

https://www.digitbin.com/install-chrome-extensions-android/amp/