# Develop Chrome Mobile Extension

Tags: mobile-chrome

Someone help me. I need to develop a mobile extension for chrome. So it's like a mobile app, on android. Is this possible? Any materials of help? Thanks.﻿

Comment: Did you try to google?

Comment: Yes...haven't gotten much. Tried Chrome App Dev Tool, but my app won't launch :(

Comment: then post what have you tried, how, and what errors did you get, otherwise no one will know how to help you and no one will post an entire tutorial here

Comment: Well, I just get a blank screen and it stays like that. This was after using Chrome Dev Editor to delploy to mobile

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Chrome extensions are not supported in mobile. checkout  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10606887/3949569